# Operator whose spectrum is given compact set

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a compact subset.

Since $A$ is compact and metric space, it is separable, say $\overline{\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n=1}^\infty}=A$.

Let $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be the Hilbert space consisting of $L^2$-summable sequences and $\lbrace e_n\rbrace_{n=1}^\infty$ be the canonical basis of $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Define an operator $T\colon\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$ by sending $e_n$ to $a_ne_n$. I want to prove that $A=\sigma(T)$, where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$.

What I can prove is that $A=\overline{\lbrace a_n\rbrace_{n=1}^\infty}\subset \sigma(T)$ because each $a_n$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $\sigma(T)$ is closed. How can I prove the other inclusion, namely $\sigma(T)\subset A$?

Comment: I'm interested in where is the question from and its background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\lambda$ in not is $A$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ with $\lvert\lambda-a_n\rvert>\epsilon$ for all $n$. Use this to write down a bounded inverse for $T-\lambda\cdot\mathrm{Id}$.

Comment: I think that now I can solve it. Thank you.

Comment: @user8484: You are welcome. There is no hurry for accepting answers. In fact, there are *drawbacks* in accepting answers too quickly. This might be more important for less localized questions that this one.