# Do we have $T=I$ if $\sigma_{p}(T)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let H be a complex infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $T\in B(H)$. Is it true that $T=I$ given $ \sigma_{p}(T)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Compact sets as point spectrum of a bounded operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/142868/721644)?

Comment: my question is for an operator T in B(H) in general, not in the case $B(H)=l_{2}$.

Comment: You should edit your question and add context.