# Prove $\forall$ compact $M:\ M \subset C\quad \exists A:l_2\rightarrow l_2, \sigma(A)=M$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator whose spectrum is given compact set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/operator-whose-spectrum-is-given-compact-set)
>   [Can spectrum “specify” an operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/can-spectrum-specify-an-operator)

Prove that for each nonempty $M$ - compact subset of $\mathbf{C}$ exists operator $A:l_2 \rightarrow l_2$, such that $\sigma(A) = M$, where $\sigma$ denotes spectrum.

Comment: Since $M$ is separable, let $\{\lambda_n\}$ a dense sequence in $M$. Define $A$ by $A(e_n)=\lambda_n e_n$, where $e_n$ is the sequence whose $n$-th term is $1$ and the others $0$. Show that it's indeed a continuous operator, that the spectrum contains all the $\lambda_n$ and then use the fact that the spectrum is closed. For the reserve direction, use the fact that is $z\notin M$ then we can find a $\delta$ such that for all $n$, $|z-\lambda_n|\geq \delta$. Then you can find an inverse to $A-zI$.

Comment: It's not the answer, but may be helpful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66345/example-of-a-compact-set-that-isnt-the-spectrum-of-an-operator -- see there Notes and Comments.

Comment: You want to assume $M$ to be non-empty since the spectrum of a (bounded) operator is never empty. Davide's construction and the one using multiplication operators are both mentioned in the linked thread "Can spectrum "specify" an operator?" (that question was the motivation for the question Damian linked to).